# Unity UI Text with markup tags - "String too long for TextMeshGenerator"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Text UI component in which I have 20 lines of 100 character long columns. This works fine. But if I try to enclose each character inside `<color> </color>` tags to give them different colors, I get the following error messages:

> String too long for TextMeshGenerator. Cutting off characters.
>
> ArgumentException: Mesh can not have more than 65000 vertices

I don't understand why the tags count towards the character limit, or why they increase the number of vertices.

What would be the best way to solve this? I am using Unity version 5.4.1f1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that Unity uses 4 vertices/2 triangles per character, and that Rich text effects and the Outline/Shadow effects duplicate geometry when applied (I am currently using Outline and  on `Text.text` and can easily get the too-many-vertices message with much, much smaller strings than 20x100 chars).

My use case is a scrolling activity log, slightly different than your case.  Solutions people have suggested for my issues:

- Use a "paging" system instead of by-line-scrolling, so a limited amount of text is displayed at any given time but it all remains accessible
- Use a 3rd-party solution like TextMesh Pro
- Add multiple `Text` elements to the `Scroll View` content window, so that no Text can be overwhelmed with vertices, and use `Content Size Fitter` to keep the scrolling functionality

Haven't attempted these yet, maybe something will work for you.

Comment: FWIW, I ended up using TextMesh Pro, which has it's own Text replacement.  That component was able to treat rich text characters as still having only 4 vertices, so my big text blocks were bounded by the "true" limit of the Text component, about 16k chars (~65000 / 4).

Comment: TextMeshPro is horrible if all you want is to display plain text longer than 200 lines or so. It's a heavy duty install, requires code changes, does not come with a mono font, defaults are wrong, colours are weird, does not support enough characters, and in my testing still cuts out at around 4000 lines. I'm prepared to do extra work on paging just to avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

Having encountered this stupifyingly dumb bug today, I discovered that in my case it stemmed from the default Arial font (which is owned by Microsoft) not being resizeable inside Unity, apparently resulting in >20k triangles for a single word rendered on the canvas.

Switching to other font styles solved the problem for me.

Thanks to:
https://youtu.be/ccYJOT7bUUY